# How to get the line number of a pattern in R

Tags: html, r

I have a html file. I am trying find all line number of a pattern "<table". So here I have:

```
line_num = grep("<table", html_file)
line_num
```

The output gives me the lines that contain pattern "<table":

```
## [1] 199 217 219
```

**However, my problem is that in line 217, the pattern "<table" has appeared twice. Therefore I want my output to look like:**

```
## [1] 199 217 217 219
```

So it prints line number for every appearance of the pattern "<table". How do I do this? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `str_count` to count the number of times a pattern occurs, drop the 0 counts and repeat the `line_num` count number of times.

```
line_num <- grep("<table", html_file)
line_count <- stringr::str_count(html_file, "<table")
line_count <- line_count[line_count != 0]
rep(line_num, line_count)
```